# Swift5: obtain brightness/light level from the camera

Tags: swift, camera, qr-code

I have this code, which is an extension of AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate:

```swift
internal func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let captureSession = captureSession else { return }
        captureSession.stopRunning()
        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        }
    }
```

And is called when it 'views' a qr code:

```swift
let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        
        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
```

What I want to do is to add a new functionality, which is, as soon as I open the camera, to know what is the luminosity of the back camera.

I found everywhere that they use this:

```swift
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, 
                  didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, 
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

But it seems to me that it is not in AvFoundation anymore.

Comment: the last method you mention is from `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` which works fine. Use `myVideoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(...`

Comment: What would that `miVideoOutput` be in my case?  I only have this: 
`captureSession = AVCaptureSession() `
`let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput`
`let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the "luminosity" of camera you mention is some kind of a light level metric. I know several ways to measure it.

I imagine, there must already be defined a videoDevice somewhere in your code: `let videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice`. If you don't store it separately, get it from `videoInput.videoDevice`.

- Check `videoDevice.iso`. The lower is value - the brighter lighting conditions are. It's a KVO property, so you can observe it's change in realtime.
- Check `videoDevice.exposureDuration`. Same: lower value → brighter lighting conditions. Exposure duration is basically what the iOS system camera adjusts for better night mode shots.
- As you mentioned, you could also get a realtime pixel buffer from your camera to analyze. Like to build a histogram and compare light pixels to dark etc.

In your camera class:

```
/// You already have the session
private let session = AVCaptureSession()

/// Define a video output (probably you did that already, 
/// otherwise how would your camera scan QRs at all)
private let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

/// Define a queue for sample buffer
private let videoSampleBufferQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "videoSampleBufferQueue")
```

Then add output to session:

```
if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput){
    session.addOutput(videoOutput)
}
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoSampleBufferQueue)
```

And implement `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    // Handle the pixelBuffer the way you like
}
```

Comment: great! I already got it so thank you very much. 
Just a little thing for you to edit, in the second block of code it says `output`, it should say `videoOutput`.